# shell script where bc loses precision

Tags: shell, math, bc

```
#! /bin/sh
a1=260
a2=9150
echo "$a1 * 100 / $a2" | bc
```

the output is

```
2
```

where it should be

```
2.8415
```

why is precision lost although I'm using `bc`?

Answer (score 7):

Try this (easy to re-use, you just need to remember to prepends the math expression with `scale=N`) :

```
$ echo "scale=10; $a1 * 100 / $a2" | bc
2.8415300546
```

As you can see, you can specify the scale length like you want.

See

```
man bc | less +/^' *scale \(\s*exp
```

Answer (score 4):

You can load the math library: bc -l

```
#! /bin/sh
a1=260
a2=9150
echo "$a1 * 100 / $a2" | bc -l
```

the output is

```
2.84153005464480874316
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for better arithmetic:

```
awk -v a1=260 -v a2=9150 'BEGIN{printf("%.4f\n", (a1 * 100 / a2))}'
```

**output:** 2.8415

Comment: in what way is it better it looks more complicated

Comment: @user568109: I just meant awk provides better arithmetic capabilities than standard bash btw which part is looking complicated to you?

Comment: you can do it with bc easily and OP did not ask for awk

Comment: `bc` is designed especially for math, I don't see any relevant point where `awk` will be better, and moreover, he uses already `bc`

Comment: @user568109 Where exactly did I say that `awk is better than bc` I just presented another option to perform floating point arithmetic not available in standard bash (bc is a an external tool as well).